# Cant build electron app without code signing

Tags: node.js, electron

I've tried electron-builder and electron-packager, and I get this Error

```
Error: Command failed: codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2
```

I don't need it to be code signed or the app store, I just need it to run on my computer.

build

```
"build":  "electron-packager ./public --app-version 1.4.3 --platform darwin --icon ./public/icon.icns --out ./dist --overwrite"
```

I've tried electron packager and electron builder.

Answer (score 4):

You should follow this guide of [Code Signing](https://www.electron.build/code-signing) if you are developing mac application.

**But if you want to Disable Code Signing During the Build Process on macOS**

Run this command in your terminal:

`export CSC_IDENTITY_AUTO_DISCOVERY=false`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing the problem  in what you posted. These are the cmds I use for electron-packager - "package-mac", "package-win". Maybe they will help.

Electron-builder use "pack" and "dist" and I have not included the associated scripts for those.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "APP_DEV=true electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --asar --ignore=/dist --ignore=/build --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --asar --ignore=/dist --ignore=/build --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build -mw"
  },
```

Comment: That’s what I thought, but I keep getting that error no matter what I do

Comment: Added build script

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `electron-builder` to build the application in MAC, you can simply disable the code signing by adding [-c.mac.identity=null](https://www.electron.build/code-signing.html) to your `electron-builder` params as follows.

```
electron-builder --mac --config -c.mac.identity=null
```